# Futex code walkthrough- returning EFAULT

Tags: kernel, arm, inline-assembly, futex

In the `futex_wake_op function` of futex.c in the Linux kernel source,I was trying to understand how the control reaches [this](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/kernel/futex.c#L940) point.This happens when in the above said function,the `futex_atomic_op_inuser` returns -EFAULT,and yet the `uaddr2` is writable.

But from the [source](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/arch/arm/include/asm/futex.h#L36) of `futex_atomic_op_inuser`, I see that it returns -EFAULT only on `if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, uaddr, sizeof(int)))`.

`futex_atomic_op_inuser`in turn calls a the `__futex_atomic_op` macro where I see a -EFAULT in the code but I'm told that path to EFAULT does not involve calling `__futex_atomic_op`

How does the control reach the aforementioned point (i.e.**if (!fshared)goto retry_private**;)then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is two questions. The path to EFAULT does not involve calling `__futex_atomic_op`.

Comment: @Igor I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

`access_ok` is only meant to check if the address range is valid for the given access, and even for that it can not always give a definite answer. See the comments in the source:

```
 * Returns true (nonzero) if the memory block may be valid, false (zero)
 * if it is definitely invalid.
 *
 * Note that, depending on architecture, this function probably just
 * checks that the pointer is in the user space range - after calling
 * this function, memory access functions may still return -EFAULT.
```

Next, even if the block is valid, it may not be present in memory (swapped out). `futex_atomic_op_inuser` calls `pagefault_disable`, which disables the normal swap-in process so you will get a hard fault, returning `-EFAULT` from `__futex_atomic_op`.

In conclusion all this means that the point in question will be reached if:

1. the address is invalid but slips past the check in `access_ok`, or
2. it is valid but currently swapped out.